# Keep all names from list to data.frame

Tags: r, list, dataframe

When converting a list into a data.frame, R names the variables automatically by concatenating all the sublists names. However it appears that it only keeps the last name when a list is of length 1. Is there a way to enforce a full path name for the variable name?

MWE:

```
> l <- list(a = list(b = 1), c = 2)
> l
$a
$a$b
[1] 1
$c
[1] 2

> data.frame(l)
  b c
1 1 2

> ll <- list(a = list(b = 1, bb = 1), c = 2)
> data.frame(ll)
  a.b a.bb c
1   1    1 2
```

Here I would like to have `a.b` as the name of the variable of `data.frame(l)` like it does for `data.frame(ll)`.

Comment: but problem is that `unlist` does not have the same behaviour as `as.data.frame` when dealing with, eg. `list(a = 1, b = 1:3)`

Comment: sure I can, it uses recycling of the shortest variable. But of course lengths have to be _compatible_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to create a function that converts the list into a data frame with `as.data.frame()` and then sets the names to the desired values in a second step:

```
list_df <- function(list) {
  df <- as.data.frame(list)
  names(df) <- list_names(list)
  return (df)
}
```

Obviously, defining `list_names()` is the hard part. One possibility is to recurse through the nested lists:

```
list_names <- function(list) {

  recursor <- function(list, names) {
    if (is.list(list)) {
      new_names <- paste(names, names(list), sep = ".")
      out <- unlist(mapply(list, new_names, FUN = recursor))
    } else {
      out <- names
    }
    return(out)
  }

  new_names <- unlist(mapply(list, names(list), FUN = recursor))
  return(new_names)
}
```

This works for your two examples:

```
l <- list(a = list(b = 1), c = 2)
ll <- list(a = list(b = 1, bb = 1), c = 2)
list_df(l)
##   a.b c
## 1   1 2
list_df(ll)
##   a.b a.bb c
## 1   1    1 2
```

It also works for a list that is not nested, as well as for a list with deeper nesting:

```
ls <- list(a = 1, b = 3)
lc <- list(a = list(b = 1, bb = 1), c = 2, d = list(e = list(f = 1, ff = 2), ee = list(fff = 5)))
list_df(ls)
##   a b
## 1 1 3
list_df(lc)
##   a.b a.bb c d.e.f d.e.ff d.ee.fff
## 1   1    1 2     1      2        5
```